# In DFP, Is it possible to track where the click originated (referrer report)?

Tags: google-dfp, ad-server

I would like to know exactly on which page the click originated in my reports.
This is valuable when you want to know which creative worked better on each page.
Unfortunately creating different ad-unit for each page is not a real solution, since we have hundreds of pages.

Comment: I do this by attaching a event listener after the ad is rendered then push this data into Google Analytics. I am able then to narrow things down not only by page, time, geo location ect.

Answer (score 1):

Attach slotRenderEnded to the pubads()
Ignore the event.isEmpty responses. 
Capture the AD slot /Company/Position/AdSlot inside DFP.
Capture the DFP Creative ID.
Then I push this data into Google Analytics.

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
                if (!event.isEmpty) {
                    if (!$.isEmptyObject(event.slot.i)) {dfp_position = event.slot.i;}
                    if (!$.isEmptyObject(event.slot.w)) {dfp_position = event.slot.w;} 
 gt.push({event: 'gtm_dfp_event',gtm: {dfp: {category: "DFP",action: dfp_position,label: event.creativeId}}});
```

The response data contains the ad URL link, you can overwrite it with an event listener that will record the click then after redirect to the DFP URL.

Answer (score 0):

DFP has no reporting facility for site metrics such as URL or page on your site.

Here is the complete list of dimensions that can be applied to DFP reports:

- Ad network name
- Ad request size
- Delivery

  - Advertiser
  - Aggregated demand channel
  - Creative
  - Creative size
  - Creative type
  - Line item
  - Line item type
  - Master and Companion creative
  - Order
- Geography

  - City
  - Country
  - Metro
  - Postal code
  - Region
- Inventory

  - Ad unit
  - Custom criteria
  - Placement
  - Targeting
- Targeting

  - Device category
- Time unit

  - Date
  - Day of week
  - Hour
  - Month and year
  - Week
- Users

  - Salesperson
- Video

  - Fallback position

Comment: Is it possible yo achieve this in any alternative way (with dfp)?

Comment: I tend to group similar pages (based on template) and create separate units per template.  I've given up on much individual page customization.